# How to access in my demo-code the following methods "addPoints()" and "getScores()"

Tags: java, inheritance

I can not understand how to access the method getScore() from class RatingCalculator and how to access the overrided method addPoints() from class CalculatorForBoxing.

```
public class Calculator {
    class Score{
        int score;
        int playerId; 
    }

    class RatingCalculator extends Score {
        ArrayList<CalculatorForBoxing> newGame;
        public CalculatorForBoxing boxer1;
        public CalculatorForBoxing boxer2;


        ArrayList<Integer> getScores(){
            return myArrayList;
        }
    }
```

here is a calculator for a specific sport

```
     class CalculatorForBoxing extends RatingCalculator implements RateByAccumulatingPoints {

        int forbiddenKicks;
        int successfullKicks;

        public  CalculatorForBoxing  (int playerId, int score, int forbiddenKicks, int successfullKicks ) {
            this.playerId = playerId;
            this.score = score;
            this.forbiddenKicks = forbiddenKicks;
            this.successfullKicks = successfullKicks;
            }
        public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
            this.playerId = playerId;
        }

        public int getPlayerId() {
            return playerId;
        }
        public void setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }
        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        @Override
        public void addPoints(int playerId, int points) {
            //some code
            }
        }
    interface RateByAccumulatingPoints {
         void addPoints(int playerId, int points );
        }
```

here i need to demonstrate how calculators work for different kinds of sport

```
    class Judge extends RatingCalculator  {

        // here my simple scenario;
        void rate(RatingCalculator rc){
            newGame = new ArrayList<CalculatorForBoxing>();
            newGame.add(boxer1 = new CalculatorForBoxing(01, 0, 0, 4));
            newGame.add(boxer2 = new CalculatorForBoxing(02, 0, 0, 5));
            newGame.addPoints(01, 20); //haven't access here
            newGame.getScores();       //haven't access here
        }
    }
```

Comment: new game is your array list not your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code newGame is an array list not the class object which is why you're unable to call addPoints and getScores.

In this scenario you just need to simply call getScores() as it is in your base class. however you would need to add the function addPoints to the base class in order to be able to call it from classes that extend it.